# next() always gives the same index with a KFold generator

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380636/sklearn-kfold-acces-single-fold-instead-of-for-loop) to generate kfold indices for cross-validation using sklean's KFold.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

When I use a for loop, everything works perfectly:

```
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
```

gives me:

```
TRAIN: [1 2 3 4] TEST: [0]
TRAIN: [0 2 3 4] TEST: [1]
TRAIN: [0 1 3 4] TEST: [2]
TRAIN: [0 1 2 4] TEST: [3]
TRAIN: [0 1 2 3] TEST: [4]
```

However, when I use `next()`, I always get the same index no matter how many times I run this:

```
train_idx, test_idx = next(kf.split(X))
print(train_idx, test_idx)

[1 2 3 4] [0]
```

Is there anything I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: because you keep calling `.split` and *then* `next`. you need to keep calling `next` on what is returned by `.split`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, you need to call `next()` on what is being returned by `split()`.

Code to try:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

kf = KFold(n_splits=5)

randomIter = kf.split(X)
train_idx, test_idx = next(randomIter)
print(train_idx, test_idx)
train_idx, test_idx = next(randomIter)
print(train_idx, test_idx)
train_idx, test_idx = next(randomIter)
print(train_idx, test_idx)
train_idx, test_idx = next(randomIter)
print(train_idx, test_idx)
```